# Unable to pass correct item of a list to a child component or type it correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, trpc.io

So I am rendering a list of members in nextjs which I get from a trpc call and render as a list.  I want to pass a specific member's info into a modal which is opened onClick, but I am getting type errors and the info that is loading into the modal is only that of the last person in the list.

Here is the parent component:

```
const ShowUsers = () => {
  const { householdId } =
    useContext(GlobalContext);
  const getHouseholdMembers = api.household.getHouseholdMembers.useQuery({
    householdId,
  });
  const [showingUserInfoModal, setShowingUserInfoModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
      {getHouseholdMembers.data &&
        getHouseholdMembers.data[0]?.members.map((member) => (
          <div
            key={member.id}
            className="my-2 flex items-center gap-3"
          >
            <Image
              className="rounded-full"
              src={member.image ?? ""}
              width={40}
              height={40}
              alt={member.name ?? ""}
            />
            <div className="flex flex-col">
              <h3
                className="text-lg"
                onClick={() => setShowingUserInfoModal(true)}
              >
                {member.name}
              </h3>
              <p className="italic">
                {member.role === "USER" ? "Member" : "Founder"}
              </p>
            </div>
            <UserInfoModal
            showingUserInfoModal={showingUserInfoModal}
            setShowingUserInfoModal={setShowingUserInfoModal}
            {...member}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and the modal component:

```
type UserInfoModalProps = {
  showingUserInfoModal: boolean;
  setShowingUserInfoModal: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  member: RouterOutputs["household"]["getHouseholdMembers"][0]["members"][number];
};

const UserInfoModal = ({
  showingUserInfoModal,
  setShowingUserInfoModal,
  ...member
}: UserInfoModalProps) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        isOpen={showingUserInfoModal}
        onClose={() => setShowingUserInfoModal(false)}
      >
        <div className="">{member.name}</div> < --- this shows an error 
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The error Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ member: User; }' is shown, and onscreen only shows the name of the last person in the list.  When I put {member.member.name} it doesn't complain in the IDE but onscreen it fails to compile with 'Unable to read properties of undefined'.

How can I correctly send the info of only the member of the clicked on to the modal?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is not helpful to reproduce the problem. However, I tried taking a look at it. Are you sure about that "**the info that is loading into the modal is only that of the last person in the list**"? Can you double-check that only 1 modal is active and not many modals for every member, each one stacked upon the other?

Comment: You are using a global boolean state `showingUserInfoModal` to trigger if a modal is open or not. That means that if someone clicks on **any** `<h3>` the state will become true and **all** modals will render. Furthermore, when someone closes **one** modal, state goes back to false and **all** modals close. You need separate states on each modal, or a global object state that determines which modal will open based on `member.id`.

Comment: You are right, that's exactly what's happening.  Thank you!